# creating a Collection<object> from object

Tags: java, collections

I have an object: p
I need: Collection allThePs

I tried:

```
Collection<object> allThePs = (Collection<object>) p;
```

as well as:

```
Collection<object> allThePs;
allThePs.add(p);
```

From what I've found, I'm not sure what I'm trying to do is possible because a collection is abstract. How do I get this as a collection?

Comment: I assume you mean `Object` not `object` and it is possible, I suggest you try it.

Comment: Yes it should be `Collection<Object> allThePs;`

Comment: my type isn't actually "object", I just knew that it was irrelevant what the object was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize the collection with an actual implementation of `Collection`. For example:

```
Collection<Object> allThePs = new ArraylList<>();
allThePs.add(p);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this.

```
    Object o = "Something";
    Collection<Object> allThePs = new ArrayList<>();
    allThePs.add(o);
```

You cant use just a Collection class to store data. You need to have one of its implementations. Eg: ArrayList